# too many initializers for struct and array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, binary, typedef

Can someone help me?

Two errors that I couldn't solve:

- too many initializers and
- type(s) preceding 'date'

---

This is a header file `book.h`

```
struct date
{

    int date;  >>>>the type(s preceding'date'),don't know what is this??

    int month;

    int year;
};

typedef struct {

    char book_name[51];

    char book_ID[7];

    char author[31];

    char publisher[31];

    struct date book_date;

    double price;


}BOOK;
```

---

This is a `.cpp` file

```
void main()

{

    int i;

    BOOK bk_detail[10] ={

        {"Harry Potter","B1001","JK ROWLING","Little Brown",{30,6,1997},56.00},

        {"Me Before You","B1002","Jojo Moyer","Penguin Group",{3,6,2004},58.00},

        {"Game Of Throne","B1003","George RR Martin","Snow Dany",{4,4,1990},69.00},

        {"Maze Runner","B1004","James Dashner","Chicken Mouse",{3,3,2003},55.00},

        {"Papertown","B1005","John Green","Dutton Penguin",{16,8,2008},47.00},

        {"Twilight","B1006","Stephenie Meyer","Little Brown",{12,7,2005},56.00},

        {"The Hunger Game","B1007","Suzanne Collins","Scholastic Corporation",{3,9,2006},69.00},

        {"No Man Sky","B1008","Nathan Stuart","Littlefinger Group",{4,8,2014},55.00},

        {"Resist the Temptation","B1009","Jon Snow","The Night Watch",{8,9,1998},69.00},

        {"To Code","B1010","Daenerys Targaryen","Dragons BB",{5,3,1997},56.00}

    }; 
    FILE*books_detail=fopen("book_detail.bin","wb");
    if (books_detail == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR...\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    fwrite(&bk_detail,sizeof(bk_detail[0]),10,books_detail);

    fclose(books_detail);

}
```

I've followed the tutorial steps but it appears that it still have errors,why that's still have these two error.(PS, I'm new to coding.)

Comment: What compiler/OS do you use? (my gcc 5.4.1 installation under Linux accepts that without complaining).

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi: Ooo!  That's exciting.  I looked at it and immediately thought - that can't be right .... but http://cpp.sh/8xj4r.  OK, I don't understand what is going on!  OP: We need a [mcve], and the *complete* error message.

Comment: @MartinBonner " OK, I don't understand what is going on!" It works with default generated constructors. It won't the moment you want to add a/any constructor.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi: So why does the OP have a problem (there are no constructors).  Hey ho: to answer that we will need a [mcve].

Comment: @MartinBonner "So why does the OP have a problem (there are no constructors)" Ok, to be precise, I meant to say "*With my gcc5.4.1 installation*, it works up to the moment I add any constructor". This is why my initial question of: "What compiler/OS the OP is using?"

Answer (score 2):

The second error is a consequence of the first.  The first error, is that given:

```
 struct date {
```

a member called `date` is a constructor - and constructors can't be preceeded by a type.  To put it another way, you can't have a member variable with the same name as the struct or class.

The fix is to change it to:

```
      int day_of_month;
```

**Edit**: Except that [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/8xj4r) is entirely happy with:

```
// Example program

struct Foo
{
    int Foo;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.Foo = 1;

    return foo.Foo;
}
```

(which has the same "problem").

I would *strongly* recommend that rather than using arrays of `char`, you use `std::string` throughout.  It makes a lot of code *much* simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your struct is named "date" and it has a member variable named "date". The compiler throws an error because they are named the same.

An easy way to think about this is if you made a type of

int int;

Since int is a type, you cannot name variable the same name as a type.

Comment: "An easy way to think about this is if you made a type of `int int;`" Ummm... since when `date` is a reserved word in C++?

Comment: I've edited it to be more clear. The reason it is similar is that it is a type. I never said it was a reserved word.